# Sticking bootstrap menu in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this menu in Wordpress (it's based on bootstrap)and I want it to stick to top when scrolled, but have some content on top of the menu:

Image:
[image]
Code:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://x">
<img src="logo" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive" title=" Logo">
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation text-right" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-8"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
</ul></div>                     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<nav id="mobile-navigation" class="text-center" role="navigation">
<div id="mobile-menu-trigger">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-8"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10"><a href="http://x">Link</a></li>
</ul></div>                     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide you code in running environment..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the bootstrap, you can add its class "navbar-fixed-top" to the menu. The example of usage you can see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

If you just need to display the already attached menu correctly on top of the rest of the content - just use CSS z-index:

```
.menu-wrapper {
  z-index:99999;
}
```

UPD: use [this pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky) to add classes on scrolling

Comment: I added the class and the menu goes to the top over my content, but the menu has 40px top content and when i scroll i want that to be hidde. Like in the image..

Comment: You need to add the indent to menu with css: {top:50px} (50px for example - it is the height of your content above), then, for example add the class "sticky" with JS to the content above, and add CSS "position: fixed;top:0"

Comment: I'm thinking to add margin-top: 40px (height of the content row) and to clear the margin once it's scrolled, any ideea how I can do that?

Comment: Use this pattern to add classes on scrolling - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky